# "Подавить веселье" - объясните предложение (для иностранца)

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами это предложение:

*В состоянии ли Вы подавить веселье, если это может кого-либо задеть?*

Comment: "Подавить веселье" — стилистически неудачно. Корректно: "сдержать свое веселье", "не показывать свое веселье".

Answer (score 2):

Можете ли Вы не казаться весёлым, если это может кого-либо задеть?

Answer (score 0):

Можете ли вы не веселиться, если это кого-то задевает (обижает)?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь трудно упростить, не нарушив смысла.
Получается или еще сложнее, или неточно.

Попробую пояснить.
***Представьте, что кому-то будет неприятен ваш смех над какой-то шуткой или анекдотом. Или у кого-то горе - и вы об этом знаете, а у вас праздник.
И вот вас спрашивают, "Можете ли вы в этой ситуации не смеяться, не проявлять радости (хотя бы внешне)?".***

//--------
Вы тест-анкету заполняете на русском, нет?
Может вам стоит просто перевести на более понятный вам язык?
Это гораздо точнее и правильнее сделают в параллельном англоязычном сообществе, вы там зарегистрированы. Но в принципе я могу попробовать перевести на английский (более или менее адекватно) или немецкий (много хуже).